# What's the different of using Python lambda inside and outside a function?

Tags: python, lambda

I am studying Python lambda today and I wrote a test case:

```
def iterator1(source):
    print(source)
    return source

def iterator2(source):
    source1 = lambda : source
    print(source1)
    return source1

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [2,3,4,5,6,7]

a = iterator1(lambda: zip(x,y))
b = iterator2(zip(x,y))

for i in range(2):
    tmp = a()
    for j in tmp:
        print(j)

print("==============")

for i in range(2):
    print(i)
    tmp2 = b()
    for j in tmp2:
        print(j)
```

Both two iterators return lambda function.

The difference is that I pass the lambda outside the function in iterator1 but construct a lambda in iterator2. I expected the two result are the same, but it doesn't;

```
<function <lambda> at 0x7f44da7645e0>
<function iterator2.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f44da764670>
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
(5, 6)
(6, 7)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
(5, 6)
(6, 7)
==============
0
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
(5, 6)
(6, 7)
1
```

So I am confused about this usage of lambda, is that some internal mechanism I don't know to deal with lambda function?

Comment: `iterator2` returns type `iterator` and iterator can only be consumed once, hence you see this behavior

Answer (score 0):

For `a` what's happening should be clear. The `zip` iterator gets created each time you do `a()` - so you have 2 unique iterators to go over in your for loop:

```
for i in range(2):
    tmp = a()
    for j in tmp:
        print(j)
```

For `b`, the `zip` iterator is created only once, here:

```
b = iterator2(zip(x, y))
```

You merely fetch that twice in the loop:

```
tmp = b()
```

So the first time the for loop runs:

```
for i in range(2):
    print(i)
    tmp2 = b()
    for j in tmp2:
        print(j)
```

The zip is iterated over:

```
0
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
(5, 6)
(6, 7)
```

The next time you call `b()`, the same `zip` iterator is returned. But you had just exhausted that iterator in the last loop. So there is nothing left in the iterator to go over, resulting in:

```
1
```

You can verify it by checking the `id()` of `tmp`:

```
print(id(tmp))
```

First loop:

```
2109174712000  # <- different IDs
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
(5, 6)
(6, 7)
2109174711872  # <- different
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
(5, 6)
(6, 7)
=======
```

Second loop:

```
0
2109174711936  # <- same ID
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
(5, 6)
(6, 7)
1
2109174711936  # <- same ID
```